# Is google place autocomplete component in vue js free?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, google-places-api

I have implemented google place autocomplete: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-autocomplete

I enabled the api on google cloud.
I was wonder if it's free: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing

Is it SKU: Basic Data ?

Answer (score 0):

vue-google-autocomplete package is free but you should attach credit or debit card to get google map API key and then be charged for it, if you have many visits https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
development version is free

here is google service which is wrapped by npm package for vue https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Google map API is included in vue-google-autocomplete ? I mean, just using vue-google-autocomplete with the requests to the API is free or will I be charged to do that ?

Comment: It is google map api https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete you cant use it independently

Comment: Google Maps Platform requires using API key with billing account enabled. If your usage is low (less than 200$) you don't pay otherwise you will be charged. Google just define a free usage limit as 200$.

Comment: @xomena So, using vue-google-autocomplete package, is free ? Independently from the requests to the API ?